# Is it possible to calculate volume of cuboid with its space diagonal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, systems-of-equations

Given only the cuboid's space diagonal $S$, it it possible to calculate the volume of the cuboid? This question could be reframed like this: do two cuboids exist such that they have the same volume, but different space diagonals (or vice versa)?

To prove that it is possible to do that we have to prove that the following system of equations has no real solutions for $a,b,c ≠ d,e,f$:

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2 + e^2 + f^2$$
$$abc = def$$

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Given the space diagonal you can make a cuboid with that diagonal that's nearly planar, so the volume can be as small as you like. In the limit you can imagine a cuboid with $0$ third dimension, so $0$ volume.

Comment: In the reals you can just about take four of the variables to be anything you want and solve the simultaneous equations for the other two.  You can run into trouble if one of the squares needs to be negative.

Comment: Note that *axis-aligned bounding boxes* are commonly used in computer graphics (as well as some other computational geometry stuff). They are defined using two vertices, one with the minimum coordinate values, and the opposing one (with maximum coordinates). For AABBs, the Cartesian coordinate components of the diagonal vector correspond to the width, height, and depth of the AABB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 27 = 3^2+3^2+3^2 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 5^2 $$
and
$$ 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 27 \neq 5 = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 5. $$
On the other hand,
$$ 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 6 = 36 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 9 $$
and
$$ 2^2+3^2+6^2 = 49 \neq 89 = 2^2+2^2+9^2. $$